# Google Map v3 Initializing with horizontal gray line w/ Foundation in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3, zurb-foundation

Seems to be CSS related because initializing the map in a simple HTML page works just fine. I have added suggested CSS to fix known issues (below), but can't seem to get rid of this.

```
#map {
    *, *:before, *:after {
        -moz-box-sizing: content-box!important;
        -webkit-box-sizing: content-box!important;
        box-sizing: content-box!important;
    }
    img {
        max-width: none;
        height: auto;
    }
    label {
        width: auto;
        display: inline;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like a rounding issue. Is your map container height based on pixels or percent value ?

Comment: This bug is not isolated to Foundation.

Comment: This bug is present in Bootstrap 3 too. Don't think there is "an answer" just yet.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone else looking for a temp solution for this bug:

CSS

```
.map *, .map *:before, .map *:after {
    -webkit-transform: none !important; 
}
```

SASS

```
.map {
  *, *:before, *:after {    
    -webkit-transform: none!important;
  }  
}
```

Comment: Should be noted that this will disable dragging of the map.

Comment: This is because `-webkit-transform: none !important;` should not be applied to all `div`

Try: `.gm-style div div *{ -webkit-transform: none !important; }`

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be a rendering bug with Chrome (I can replicate it in v 34.0.1847.131), rather than with your CSS. It's been fixed in Canary (v 36.0.1973.2 canary).

According to [this bug thread](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6594#c17) on gmaps-api-issues:

> The fix is in Chrome 35, which is currently scheduled for release in mid-May (you can switch to the beta channel to get the fix now or verify it in a Canary build - http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel).

Until then, like @user699242 suggested, removing any heading tags (`h1`, `h2`, etc.) in your page seems to fix it. Of course, that's semantically unappealing though, might be better just to wait.

Answer (score 1):

```
.gm-style div div *{ 
    -webkit-transform: none !important;
}
```

Note: Does the same as Nathans solutions, but also guarantees that the maps is still dragable. However it's just a temporary solution.

Comment: I would have preferred it you would add the exceptions instead of down voting it. Because I think there are quite a few people where this solution would be sufficient.

Comment: Well, comments are unfortunately too limited in term of formatting to efficiently explain the problems that your solution

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it has something to do with the following which is added inline to images by Google:

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0px)
```

Finally narrowed it down to h tags. If I removed all the h tags (h1, h2, etc.), the gray line disappears. So, seems like a Chrome bug (v 34.0.1847.116).

Comment: I had this problem too and tried removing my `h` tags and it also fixed it. Not a good fix though. Has a Chrome bug report for this been filed yet?

Comment: Confirmed removing heading tags appears to resolve this but it is not a sustainable fix.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening for me on my site http://www.shortwave.am/ as well, but only in the newest version of Chrome (I had Version 33.x before which was for some reason not updating and the problem was not there, but since I changed to the newest I have the issue).

It is fine on Firefox though.

Can you post a link to your site as an example please?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem but with a *vertical* gray line, and it was a rounding issue.

This was due to the fact that the div containing the map canvas was set to fluid-width (50% in my case) and more often than not did lead to a *subpixel* width.

To fix my problem, I had to listen to the map canvas resize event, retrieve and round the inner width of the container of the canvas (the one with width set to 50%) and set the rounded width back to map canvas - all of this in JavaScript of course.

Here is my HTML markup :

```
<div id="mapContainer">
    <div id="mapCanvas"></div>
</div>
```

Here are my CSS rules :

```
#mapContainer {
  width: 50%;
}

#mapCanvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  float: right;
}
```

Here is the JavaScript fix :

```
var isResizing = false;

var fixMapCanvasRoundingIssue = function () {
    if (isResizing == false) {
        isResizing = true;

        var width = Math.floor(document.getElementById("mapContainer").getBoundingClientRect().width);

        $("#mapCanvas").width(width);

        // is this needed ?
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");

        isResizing = false;
    }
}
```

And here is the Google Map initialization :

```
var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("mapCanvas");

google.maps.event.addDomListener(mapCanvas, "resize", function () {
    fixMapCanvasRoundingIssue();
});

map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas , {
    ...
});

fixMapCanvasRoundingIssue();
```

Note that I set the map canvas to float to the right to prevent any tearing issue on resize. This may not be needed in your case.

Answer (score 0):

```
.gmap-container,
.gmap-container > div.gm-style,
.gmap-container > div.gm-style > div:first-child,
.gmap-container > div.gm-style > div:first-child > div > div:last-child,
.gmap-container > div.gm-style > div:first-child > div > div:last-child * {
    -webkit-transform: none!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `-webkit-transform: none !important;` doesn't work make sure your browser isn't zoomed in. Having it zoomed into 110% causes the same grey line.

Answer (score 0):

Simply switch onto newer version of API:

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.14&sensor=false"></script>
```

it worked for me!

Comment: not entirely.  it gets rid of some lines, but they are still around if you look for them

Answer (score 0):

The solution suggested by Optimiertes seems to be unfairly marked down as it worked for me.

I'd suggest caution as there may be cases when something on that level needs to be transformed, but I did the following and it worked great.

```
#map .gm-style div div *:not(.something-that-needs-transforming){
  -webkit-transform: none !important;
}
```

I'm sure in time it'll be fixed in Chrome, but annoyed me enough for now to want to fix it.

Other solutions I tried didn't allow the map to pan.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed a simple way showing the location for a restaurant. All solutions didn't work for me and so I went for the following solution, using a iFrame, with the dimensions specified in my css class:

```
<div class="fluid google_maps">
    <iframe
      width="100%"
      height="100%"
      frameborder="0" style="border:0"
      src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=PLACE_APIKEY_HERE
        &q=eiffel tower">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

Thats all to it, no javascript or anything, just a few lines of html.
Since I don't expect over 2kk visitors a day (google's free limit), it's perfect for me.
You do need to create a google API key, but that 1 minute work.

The eiffel tower, can be any address or known location, you normally fill in the google maps website.

Answer (score 0):

```
#map *, #map *:before, #map *:after { 
    -webkit-transform: none !important;
}
```

it's right way if you don't use parallax effect, but if you want to hide horizontal line with parallax effect, here is fix:

```
.gm-style > div:first-child {
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

color #000000 if your google map background color is black, if is other - change this color.

work fine with google maps parallax effect