# How to remove horizontal line on google map embed

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

I have an a line that occurs on a google map embed. I'd like to remove it.
https://i.cloudup.com/E2JFdqaIky.png <-- how it looks.

Is there a way to remove this line?

Comment: Did you use the zoom-feature of the browser?

Comment: No and I have also "scaleControl: false" on.

Comment: I mean the browsers zoom(is it set to 100%?)

Comment: Are you using [Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23123677/grey-grid-showing-up-on-google-maps/23124070#23124070)?

Comment: Yes I'm using chrome and my browser is not zoomed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Map v3 Initializing with horizontal gray line w/ Foundation in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23062573/google-map-v3-initializing-with-horizontal-gray-line-w-foundation-in-chrome)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with solution from [Google Map v3 Initializing with horizontal gray line w/ Foundation in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23062573/google-map-v3-initializing-with-horizontal-gray-line-w-foundation-in-chrome).

```
#google_map *, #google_map *:before, #google_map *:after {
    -webkit-transform: none !important; 
}
```